# Creating bar plot with frequency distribution based

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a dataframe with this kind of structure:

```
ID | Size | Value
1  | 1    | 10
2  | 2    | 20
3  | 1    | 10
4  | 1    | 10
5  | 1    | 15 
6  | 1    | 12
7  | 1    | 20
```

I want to create bar plot of the distribuition of column "Values" when the "Size" column is equal to 1.

With the current example:

1. the x-axis should have: 10, 12, 15 and 20
2. the y-axis should have 1 (for the 12, 15 and 20) and 3 for the 10

I don't have a lot of code. Basically I just created a new dataframe with only the rows where Size=1 and then performed value_counts():

```
data1 = data.loc[(data['Size'] == 1)]
count = data1['Value'].value_counts()
```

The variable `count` now has a Series object with a Value and a counter.

How can I split the value of `count` in order to have two lists (values and counters) to send to the plotting code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a histogram. It plots the distribution of a given series of values. So, you can just extract the values that you want to plot from your dataframe and then use matplotlib's [histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) function. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
to_plot = data.loc[df['Size']==1]['Value']
plt.hist(to_plot)
plt.show()
```

This is the output I get, note that I haven't done any formatting, this is just the raw output.
[image]

The above option is more flexible. But in your case you can also use the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
to_plot = data.loc[df['Size']==1]['Value']
to_plot.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use hist from matplotlib library

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist( data['Value'] )
plt.show()
```